# Clustering data with mixed attributes: timeseries and constants?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering, feature-selection

I have a data set of time series, and each time series has a set of attributes. I know I can cluster time series using dynamic time warping and k-means (https://github.com/alexminnaar/time-series-classification-and-clustering), but how can I introduce attributes for each time series that can be clustered on? Each time series would have, say, five attributes that are *not* time series (i.e. a single attribute for the whole time series).

For example, say you have a large group of people and a time series showing their heart rate throughout the day. And then you have demographic information on each person. How can you cluster people based on the time series AND the demographic information?

Comment: For example, cluster all living in region X with data from 2000 to 2005? Or all single men, for all years? Also, do you want a formula, or an intuitive answer?

Comment: @luchonacho, so for the example above, I would like to see, in general, across all demographics and heart rate information, how people cluster. So you might expect men to cluster together, and women to cluster together because their hear rate variability and demographics would be more similar. But I'd want to be outcome-agnostic. An intuitive insight into the theory on how to do it would be great (and maybe an R or Python software package that could do it)?

Comment: Your question was "how can I cluster". But now it is "How does data cluster itself". Please clarify.

Comment: @luchonacho I'm sorry, I guess I'm confused by your question. If I had a set of data with `n` samples and `m` continuous-variable features, I could feed that information into `kmeans` along with a `number of clusters` parameter, and it would assign a label for each of the `n` samples as to what cluster it belongs in. I want to do the exact same thing, except I have `n` samples, `m` features, where one of the `m` features is an independent timeseries for each sample of`n`.

Comment: Mmm, ok, I think our different backgrounds might be the source of the confusion. I'm coming from panel-data studies, where you can cluster as you like. It seems your issue is different. Maybe adding some data examples might help.

Answer (score 0):

K-means is not a good idea for DTW. It should only be used woth Bregman divergences, and DTW is not one. If you look around in literature, you will also see papers that "disprove" time series clustering as being as bad as random patterns...

k-means must also only be used on continuous numerical data. So if it inherently doesn't even work on point data, it will not work on time serries either!

Clustering is *very hard*. Don't expect magic, but a tiresome work with many iterations. Things get much harder once you need to integrate different data types, because there are infinitely many possible combinations. From a statistics point of view, most clustering results are probably not sound but rather "seeing things in clouds".